# Keydown not working properly in firefox

Tags: javascript

I want to block some special characters in my page. So I have written `keypress`, `keydown` and `paste` events to block these characters. I have some issues in keydown event, only in Firefox.

This is my code:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    var SPCHARS = [192, 222]; //for [~"`']
    var SPCHARS_ONSHIFT = [54, 109, 219, 221, 188, 190, 55]; //for [_{}'<>^&]

    var charCode = (e.which) ? e.which : e.keyCode;

    if ($.grep(SPCHARS, function (e) { return e == charCode; }).length > 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    else if (typeof e.shiftKey == "boolean" && e.shiftKey && $.grep(SPCHARS_ONSHIFT, function (e) { return e == charCode; }).length > 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}, true);
```

Issue is, When user presses right arrow key  this event suppresses the event. When debugged, I found that the code always jumps into the "else if" condition -- even if the condition is `false`. It's working fine in chrome. Any idea????

Please note, I have to use this `keydown` event because I am also using infragistics grid in my page.

Comment: Works as expected for me with FF38. Could you make a MCVE?

Comment: @blgt Thankyou for your valuable comment. I got the issue fixed. Your comment forced me to check other part of the script. And the issue is happening inside the kepress event which suppresses single quote using reqular expression. Unfortunately for both arrow key and single quote, im getting 39 as keycode. I managed by adding one more if condition using e.code == 'ArrowRight' etc. Thanks for your prompt reply.

Comment: It happens, you might want to close the question as "no longer reproducible". On a side note, in my experience the best way to differentiate between character codes and other keyboard events is to use `String.charCodeAt` and `String.fromCharCode`. The performance penalty is negligible